# Confused from touchBegan examples

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I see some examples of the touchesBegan callback use:

```
for (UITouch *touch in touches) {...}
```

while others use:

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
```

I don't understand when one would need a for loop vs not.  Can someone help me understand this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you didn't enable multitouch, then you will receive a single touch. You can retrieve it from the set `touches` (which contains a single item) using `[touches anyObject];`.

If you have enabled multitouch, then the set `touches` may contain multiple items and you have to use a loop to access all of them.

```
for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    // Your code here to handle the touch
}
```

Finally, note that using the loop will work in all cases even if you have a single touch.

Answer (score 2):

If you care about each individual touch in a multi-touch situation, loop through the collection of touches - i.e. if you need to know if *any* of the touches hit a particular location:

```
for (UITouch *touch in touches) {...}
```

If you only care that a touch occurred, or aren't supporting multi-touch, then the `[touches anyObject]` approach is fine.

Answer (score 1):

for loop, you use for multi touch!